# How to insert data with logged in user id? Laravel-6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to submit data to bidding table with logged in user id and auction id from product show method.

This is how my tables are in relation.

[image: This is how my tables are in relation]

Is it good to use ProductController or should I create another controller for bidding table?

**Product show blade**

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

 @section('content')

<div class="container">
  <div class="my-3 border">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img src="/storage/images/{{$product->image}}" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2>{{$product->name}}</h2>
        <p>{{$product->description}}</p>
        <span>Category: {{$product->category->name}}</span><br>
        <span class="text-right">Auction Ends: {{$product->auction->deadline}}</span>
        <div class="price">Initial Price: {{$product->price}}</div>

        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'BiddingsController@create', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
          <div class="form-inline">
            {{Form::number('bidamount', '',['class' => 'form-control mr-1', 'placeholder' => 'Place your bid'])}}
            {{Form::submit('Place Bid', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
          </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

**Bidding controller**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Bidding;

class BiddingsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
    $biddings = Bidding::all();

    return view('products.show' ,compact('biddings', $biddings));
}

public function create()
{
   //
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

public function show(Bidding $bidding)
{
    //
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Laravel 6 app, you can get the Logged in user using the `auth()` helper.

```
$authUser = auth()->user();
```

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-auth

Cordially

Comment: Where do I put this? In the controller?

Comment: Where you need to get the logged user.

Comment: The logged in user id should be inserted into the database when he place the bid (submit the above form). User id will be the foreign key in bidding table

Comment: You can use `Bidding::create(['bidder'=>'some value','User_id'=>auth()->user()->id])` method to create your model with the data

Answer (score 0):

You can check anytime your logged details by Auth! 
Everywhere and from anywhere you can use Auth::user()->id;
example: 
for getting logged user id in controller check by!

```
dd(Auth::user()->id);
```

If needed just use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth in the very beginning of  controller.